# How to support more devices in Android app

Tags: java, android, google-play

I'm an iOS developer, but I recently developed an Android app for a customer, because they were unable to find a developer. So I made it and it works. But, I'm a complete newbie.

My customer says that their users complain than the app is not available for the newest versions of Android. I build the app against the latest version of the SDK. How do I make it compatible with new versions of Android?

Comment: you need to update targetSdkVersion checkout this https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd

Comment: "My customer says that their users complain than the app is not available for the newest versions of Android" -- that makes little sense. Apps are always available for the latest version of Android. It's *older* versions of Android that may be a problem. I suggest that you ask for specifics (e.g., what devices exhibit the problem).

Comment: @Killer I already did that.

Comment: @CommonsWare You're right. I need more information.

Comment: you can check play store as well to check which device supports or not

Comment: It's Not just a matter of setting Minimum & Maximum Android Version, You need to implement everything with this in mind that "Is this View is gonna even Show up on a specific phone or not?". You will reach more Downloads but You will reach More Downgrade and Uninstalls If you don't Code thoughtfully. But, It's not that hard, you can make a button circular on some devices while rectangle on some other phones. be thoughful

Answer (score 0):

The Play console lets you see thousands of devices in the app ecosystem, whether they are compatible with your app, and why. [The help article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455) gives more details.